# Ball not moving in javascript pong game

Tags: javascript, canvas

> Yes I know that this is a crappy unfinished version of pong that I should be using different methods than I am.
>
> But this is my first game and my pong ball is not moving at all when used.
>
> When I run the code the ball just blinks on and off instead of moving a direction.

My javascript is: `

```js
//pong game by Henry Redder


//variables
var c = document.getElementById("canvas"); //gets the canvas element
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); //gets 2d for the canvas
var pscore = document.getElementById("gscore1").textContent; //gets the player score
var aiscore = document.getElementById("gscore2").textContent; //gets the ai score
var recx = 10; //gets the first x position
var recy = 250; //gets the first y position
var aix = 1275; //gets the first ai x position 
var aiy = 250; //gets the first ai y position
var bx = 650; //gets the first ball x position
var by = 250; //gets the first ball y position
var balldirection = 0; //0 is left and 1 is right
var ballspeedside = 10; //this is the speed of the ball in the x direction
var ballspeedup = 0; //this is the speed of the ball going up

//@variables

//functions 
function start() {
 //this function starts the update function every 10 milliseconds
 setInterval(update, 10);
}
function update() {
 //this function renders the diffenent objects on the screen
 resetcanvas();
 renderball();
 renderplayer();
 renderai();
 testballdirection();
 changeposball();
}
function renderball() {
 //this function renders the ball
 ctx.fillRect(bx,by,15,15);
}
function renderplayer() {
 //this function renders the player
 ctx.fillRect(recx, recy, 15, 75);
}
function renderai() {
 //this function renders the ai in the game
 ctx.fillRect(aix, aiy, 15, 75);
}
function resetcanvas() {
 //this function resets the canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,1300,500);
 
}
function testballdirection() {
 //this function detirmens the direction of the ball
 switch(balldirection) {
  case 0:
   //case for going left
   bx = bx * -1;
  case 1:
   //case for going right
   bx = MATH.abs(bx); //sets the value to the absolute value of itself
 }
}
document.onkeydown = function testkey(e) {
 //this function tests for keys being pressed then moves the player
 if (e.keyCode == 38) {
  if (recy > 0) {
   console.log("moving up");
   recy = recy + -20;
  }
 }
 else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
  if (recy < 450) {
   console.log("moving down");
   recy = recy + 20;
  }
 }
}
function changeposball() {
 //this function changes the x and y of the ball occordngly
 bx = bx + ballspeedside;
 by = by + ballspeedup;
}
//@functions

//start
 document.onload = start();
//@start
```

My html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> pong </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pong.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1> PONG BY HENRY REDDER</h1>
 <p id="gscore1"> 0 </p>
 <p id="gscore2"> 0 </p>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"> </canvas>
 <script src="pong.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally my css is:

```css
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Courier;
}
body {
 background-color: gray;
}
#canvas {
 background-color: white;
}
#gscore1 {
position: absolute;
font-family: Impact;
top: -20px;
left: 10px;
font-size: 50px;
}
#gscore2 {
position: absolute;
font-family: Impact;
top: -20px;
left: 1270px;
font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Your snippet has javascript errors - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` did you forget to include the relevant HTML?

Comment: Apart from your problem, why are you using testballdirection every update? You should use a variable that contains the speed of the ball. Preferably you should use a 2D vector here. A 2d vector is an value that can contain 2 values. So 1 value for up/down and 1 for sideways. You should change the speed when this is needed. But while you are setting the speed when starting the game you can do this in the start function so you do not need to do it every update, if the speed stays the same. Next to that, for games always use deltatime when moving objects.Search more info on these subjects!

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.

Change `MATH` to `Math`.